# Why can't I set a value on this form field in wordpress admin?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to get the value of a form field on submit using jQuery.  However when I try to alert it, it's shows up as undefined, with text in.

```
var title=jQuery('#fields[field_4f52672267672]').val();
alert(title);
```

It's got a funny ID though because I'm using a form plugin to create my form.  When I inspect the element it simply shows the value attribute with no value beside it, even when it contains text.  Can anyone explain what is going on please?

I've attached a screenshot of the field inspected with chrome's inspector panel.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var title=jQuery('#fields\\[field_4f52672267672\\]').val();
```

Into selectors you have to escape with 2 backslashes.